# refactor conditions within haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

beside the fact that accessibility standards discourage the use
of a link pointing to the current page, how I am supposed to 
refactor the following view code?

```
#navigation
  %ul.tabbed
    - if current_page?(new_profile_path)
      %li{:class => "current_page_item"}
        = link_to t("new_profile"), new_profile_path
    - else
      %li
        = link_to t("new_profile"), new_profile_path

    - if current_page?(profiles_path)
      %li{:class => "current_page_item"}
        = link_to t("profiles"), profiles_path
    - else
      %li
        = link_to t("profiles"), profiles_path
    ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# helpers
def current_page_class(page)
  return :class => "current_page_item" if current_page?(page)
  return {}
end

-# Haml
#navigation
  %ul.tabbed
    %li{current_page_class(new_profile_path)}
      = link_to t("new_profile"), new_profile_path
    %li{current_page_class(profiles_path)}
      = link_to t("profiles"), profiles_path
    ...
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! 

P.S.: I think I can discard the last return in the function, isn't it?

Comment: That's true; I added it for symmetry with the other `return` and to emphasize that the hash was there as a return value.

Answer (score 2):

```
#navigation
  %ul.tabbed
    %li{:class => current_page?(new_profile_path) ? "current_page_item" :nil }
      = link_to t("new_profile"), new_profile_path
    %li{:class => current_page?(profiles_path) ? "current_page_item" :nil }
      = link_to t("profiles"), profiles_path
    ...
```

Comment: thank you! Ternary opeator is more concise but I would love to obtain a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good case for a partial to me.

Comment: People, comment if you're going to downvote. Otherwise you're not adding to the discussion — you're just being a prick.

Comment: Partials could definitely help here, but you were pretty vague. A suggestion as to exactly what would go into the partial would help.